# Hidden Files In XP Mode

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, file-management, windows-xp-mode

I'm currently using a Windows 7 desktop at work, with an XP Mode virtual machine to access the Netware network our company is currently trying to eliminate. However, I have to archive old files on the network every few months to ensure legacy systems continue to function. The issue is, these files all have a fileype of three numeric characters, for example "DTLTR9.523". XP recognizes these as system files, so in the past we've had to disable the folder view option "Hide protected operating system files" to see the data.

This has worked fine in the past when using a physical xp desktop. Trying this on the new XP virtual machine however has not revealed the files. They still do not appear in explorer, even though checking folder properties there are files in the location I'm checking.

It appears any hidden files remain hidden on this system. So far I've done basic troubleshooting steps, restarting the virtual machine and host computer, as well as verifying hidden system files not on the network are also not hidden.

Is there an additional option I'm currently missing past the obvious? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_fcab_show_file_extensions.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: There's a netware client for Windows 7 that looks to be freely available for download: http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=WVA4kcizKVw~

Comment: Also, you should speak to someone about migrating this critical backup to something automated, not a drag-and-drop human operation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Windows 7 client, I'll have to have a word with our network admin if everything works correctly. I'm also currently in the process of automating the backup, I was only recently given this task. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I'm not sure what "file sharing protocol" NetWare Server uses, but if it's CIFS/SMB you might be able to do something native in Windows 7/2008 (if the server isn't IPX/SPX, I believe native Windows support for IPX/SPX was dropped a little while ago).  Otherwise, you might opt for SFTP or SCP... maybe [cWrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) wrapped in a BAT + a scheduled task will be good enough.  Good luck!

Comment: You really should try opening a cmd prompt and doing dir /a   Another command is attrib. either of those in the directory, should show hidden or system files. So CD to the directory and do that.

Comment: `The issue is, these files all have a fileype of three numeric characters, for example "DTLTR9.523". XP recognizes these as system files` No, it doesn’t. It only recognizes files with the system attribute set as system files. Are you or some program setting that attribute? `in the past we've had to disable the folder view option "Hide protected operating system files" to see the data. This has worked fine in the past when using a physical xp desktop. Trying this on the new XP virtual machine however has not revealed the files.` Probably because the XP VM is SP3 while your old systems were SP1.